# Error installing libv8 in Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, libv8

Hi I'm always having trouble with regards to libv8 when bundling my gems:

Here's the error trace:

```
Installing libv8 (3.11.8.17) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/xiruki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Using compiler: g++
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o has no symbols
In file included from ../src/accessors.cc:28:
In file included from ../src/v8.h:60:
In file included from ../src/objects-inl.h:38:
In file included from ../src/elements.h:33:
In file included from ../src/heap.h:41:
../src/store-buffer.h:229:9: error: private field 'heap_' is not used [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]
  Heap* heap_;
        ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [/Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o] Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
    from /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
    from /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
    from /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
    build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                  -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                  -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                  -S.x64  -Dv8_can_use_vfp_instructions=true
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/conversions.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/diy-fp.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fast-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/fixed-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/once.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparse-data.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/preparser-api.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/scanner.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/strtod.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/token.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/unicode.o
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/utils.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/libpreparser_lib.a
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser/preparser/preparser-process.o
  LINK(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/preparser
  CXX(target) /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@ensemblist/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.11.8.17), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.17'` succeeds
before bundling.
```

I am using MAC 10.9. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you have Xcode last version and command tools?

Comment: How can I check the version of my command tools? Thanks. Sorry newbie MAC user too.

Comment: in your error backtrace `It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher` `Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.`

Comment: try update `xcode` , and look version in bash `gcc -v`

Comment: It says:
`Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix` So I just need to update the version of my Command Line tools?

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/94) help.

Comment: Did you recently update from Mountain Lion to Mavericks?

Comment: Yup I updated to Mavericks.

Comment: Thanks all installing via `gem install libv8 -v 3.11.8.17 -- --with-system-v8` helped me.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this issue, installing the "therubyracer" gem worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue before, fixed it by the following way:

- install v8 by brew `brew install v8`
- install libv8 with system v8 `gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.17' --with-system-v8`

Hope it can help!